# How to rearrange a dict keys in increasing order (ex: date in a year as key)? python 3

Tags: python, date, dictionary

Ive been working with dictionaries recently and Ive been working on a project which includes saving events of a day to a calendar.

so the format for the key would be in the date format yyyy-mm-dd. I wanted to make it so that every 'key' that is in the dictionary would come out as according to the days. For example:the key 2015-11-10 with its events on that day and 2015-11-9 with its events, I would like 2015-11-9 and its events to be printed out first. I have tried sorting and tuples etc.. but that would only sort what is inside the key not the key itself. Any ideas or suggestions?

```
>>> calendar = {}
    >>> command_add("2015-10-12", "Eye doctor", calendar)
    ''
    >>> command_add("2015-10-12", "lunch with sid", calendar)
    ''
    >>> command_add("2015-10-29", "Change oil in blue car", calendar)
    ''
    >>> command_add("2015-10-12", "dinner with Jane", calendar)
    ''
    >>> command_add("2015-10-29", "Fix tree near front walkway", calendar)
    ''
    >>> command_add("2015-10-29", "Get salad stuff", calendar)
    ''
    >>> command_add("2015-11-06", "Sid's birthday", calendar)
    ''
    >>> command_show(calendar)
```

What I need is this:

```
>>> command_show(calendar)
        2015-10-12:
            0: Eye doctor
            1: lunch with sid
            2: dinner with Jane
        2015-10-29:
            0: Change oil in blue car
            1: Fix tree near front walkway
            2: Get salad stuff
        2015-11-06:
            0: Sid's birthday
    ''
```

Comment: Break your sentences, currently failed to understand your query.

Comment: Ive edited it to the best of my abilities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normal [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) are unordered. If you want an ordered dictionary, you have to use [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

But I guess it would be enough to iterate over the values in an ordered fashion. Usually, you do it like this:

```
for key, value in sorted(mydict.items()):
    pass  # now it is sorted in ascending order of key
```

Please note that `mydict` is still unordered. `.items()` returns a list of `(key, value)` tuples. And lists can be sorted.

### dict with list elements

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


def command_add(day, event_name, calendar):
    if day in calendar:
        calendar[day].append(event_name)
    else:
        calendar[day] = [event_name]


def command_show(calendar):
    """
    Parameters
    ----------
    calendar : dict
        The keys are dates in the format YYYY-MM-DD and the values are lists
        of events
    """
    for day, events in sorted(calendar.items()):
        print("%s:" % day)
        for i, event in enumerate(events):
            print("\t%i: %s" % (i, event))


calendar = {}
command_add("2015-10-12", "Eye doctor", calendar)
command_add("2015-10-12", "lunch with sid", calendar)
command_add("2015-10-29", "Change oil in blue car", calendar)
command_add("2015-10-12", "dinner with Jane", calendar)
command_add("2015-10-29", "Fix tree near front walkway", calendar)
command_add("2015-10-29", "Get salad stuff", calendar)
command_add("2015-11-06", "Sid's birthday", calendar)
command_show(calendar)
```

Comment: i dont want the value to be sorted but the key to be printed out in the correct order of a year and when i try this it rearranges everything but not in increasing order

Comment: Please add a minimal example of input (your dictionary) and expected output. The code I gave in my answer does sort the keys.

Comment: @Pythonbeginner I've expanded my answer.